# solr query with white space

Tags: solr

I search for a word and I get the results with facet as follows:

```
<lst name="itemtype">
<int name="Internal">108</int>
<int name="Users">73</int>
<int name="Factory">18</int>
<int name="Supply Chain Intermediaries">6</int>
<int name="Company">1</int>
<int name="Monitor/Auditor firm">0</int>
</lst>
```

Then I wrote the condition like `fq=itemtype:Factory`. I get the results. But I am not getting the results for `fq=itemtype:Supply Chain Intermediaries`.
I am thinking the problem rests with the spaces in the condition (Supply Chain Intermediaries). I tried with `urlencode` (to replace spaces with `%20`) also. But it's of no use. Can you guys please help me to solve this?

#### Update:

For single value it is working fine. I build the query like this:

```
http:localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=adidas&version=2.2&indent=on&facet=on&start=0&rows=20&fq={!raw f=itemtype}Supply Chain Intermediaries
```

But i need to write for multiple values. The original Query with out **raw** is as follows

```
http://localhost/solr/select/?q=adidas&version=2.2&indent=on&facet=on&start=0&rows=20&fq=(itemtype:Company itemtype:Supply Chain Intermediaries)
```

Can you guys please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How is your itemtype field analysed?

If it is of type string , then use:

```
fq=itemtype:"Supply Chain Intermediaries"
```

Otherwise you can also try:

```
fq=itemtype:(Supply Chain Intermediaries)
```

Assuming `OR` is the default operator in your config and `text` is the default search field, your query will get translated to:

```
fq=itemtype:Supply OR text:(Chain Intermediaries)
```

Chain and Intermediaries are searched against default search field.

Comment: This helped. thank you. But what when we have some field name with white spaces? Pls advise.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'm using http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/ by the way and there is no conversion for array input types so it must be manually done.

Comment: I'm building query using Solr Criteria(fieldname).contains(value) not working for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

I have tried different solutions mentioned here, but none of them worked. However I solved it like this:

```
fq=itemtype: *Supply\ Chain\ Intermediaries*
```

Here space will be escaped with `\`

The above string will match with the strings `Lorem Supply Chain Intermediaries Ipsum`

If you are having a word starts with `Supply Chain Intermediaries Ipsum`
then just give

```
fq=itemtype: Supply\ Chain\ Intermediaries*
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer this question directly but it may help with this problem:

**Remove the spaces before posting to Solr.**

For fields used for faceting rather than searching, it is not important to store the value with spaces. The value is simply a treated as key.  Store the field `itemtype` like so:`"supplychainintermediaries", "monitorauditorfirm"`, etc.

When you display the facet values to the user, simply use a dictionary which maps key values to display values.  Like so:

`"supplychainintermediaries" --> "Supply Chain Intermediaries"`
`"monitorauditorfirm" --> "Monitor/Auditor Firm"`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use

```
fq={!raw f=itemtype}Supply Chain Intermediaries
```

for that purpose

It tuns out that you have to use !term instead of !raw for Solr version >= 4.0

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201012.mbox/%3C4D121F73.3090706@jhu.edu%3E

Have a nice day.

Comment: I wrote my new solr query. Can you please check and give suggestion.

Comment: @Brahmaji Do you need OR operation between filters or AND operation? For AND you can simply write multiple `fq` filters. But I guess you don't have much luck with OR. May be you can try to write your values between double quotes instead, such as `fq=text:"Chain Intermediaries"`. I haven't tried that one though.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed white space issue by replacing :

```
$tmp[] = $name . ':' . $this->_escapeValue($value);
```

with :

```
$tmp[] = $name . ':' .'"'. $this->_escapeValue($value).'"';
```

Means by adding quotation after escape value in `SolrSource.php` file.