# How to use like operator in select query in Apache Solr for java?

Tags: solr

I have scenario like to get data which contain some part of that data.

like, i want supplier name from list, i have search with only three character of supplier name.
SQL Syntext : select * from suppliers where supplier_name like '%JM T%'

I need similar query for Apache Solr.

If any help, than its appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Ashish

Answer (score 5):

In Solr, you can use: `supplier_name:*JM T*`
But you'll get a little bit problem with white space: [solr query with white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790180/solr-query-with-white-space)

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your solr schema is setup, you could have supplier_name as a field then query like

Supplier_name:"JM T"