# Solr Query for filter document with white space in value in facet field

Tags: solr, solrnet

For Solr 3.6. I want to query Solr data for one of the faceted field for a filtering white space " " as a value, but I doesn't know how to do it? I have tried several times with white space, ' ' & " " but none of them work. There is a data document with white space in Solr which it shows in facet count, but filtering on it doesn't work and gives error.

Here is the example query I'm trying:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core-live/select/?q=CategoryID%3A113&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=f_brand&&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=f_wi-fi&fq=f_wi-fi:yes
```

This filters document with Yes, notice the fq with f_wi-fi:yes. I want to know how to filter documents with white spaces.

Comment: Can you share your schema file with the datatype for the field you want to filter on?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question clearly. I do not have any problem filtering on any faceted field. Filtering works fine, but I'm unable to filter for white space as " " for any faceted field. I just want to know how to write query that filters f_wi-fi=" " <-- white space. It works correctly when I write yes, no or any other value. Or may be there is something else wrong. Let me know, i'll be able to share you some portion of schema file tomorrow.

Comment: Can you check if the document f_wi-fi is stored with the white space value. I think the field if without any value will not be stored and if so you can easily use a negative query to get the results.

Comment: @Krunal - I understand your question, my thought was that the data type of the field is configured to remove whitespace for the query analyzer. If you don't want to share your schema, I encourage you to click analysis on the admin page to investigate.   http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/analysis.jsp

Comment: Please refer to this link: [Solr Query with white space][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790180/solr-query-with-white-space