# SOLR double quotes in edge_ngram field

Tags: solr

A field in the SOLR indexes for an application I'm working on is defined as follows:

```
 <field name="text" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

...and, elsewhere in schema.xml:

```
 <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">                                                                                
     <analyzer type="index"> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />  
        ...
```

This works nicely for most searches the users wish to do, e.g. it turns up 'twowords' if they search for 'two words', and so on.

However, some users also wish to search for exact strings. For example, exactly one record contains 'this exact string' amongst the many other words in the text field. If users search for that string using quotes, i.e. "this exact string", a search will turn up nothing:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=%22this%20exact%20string%22
```

Omit the quotes, and they will get plenty of hits, for example anything with 'string' in it.

Presumably, therefore, my choice of field type is not the best. Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: Can you provide some information about the input data which you are indexing?

Comment: My solution for this was a new field with only a `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory` as Tokenizer. By using relevance ranking, you would get the 100% hit from that field first, if using the same boost for both fields.

Comment: Which version of Solr that do you use?

Comment: It's SOLR 4.9.0. The text field contains a short paragraph of free text describing the record, a few keywords, URLs &c.

Comment: @knirirr This might help. [solr query with white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5800877/2254048).

Comment: @YoungHobbit - thanks, but no luck from anything there either. N.B. I am trying these queries using the interface at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/query

Comment: @knirirr Disclaimer: I don't think this will solve the problem in ideal way, but can help a bit.

You can copy the content of `text` field into a different field using the `copyField`. Now use the `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` tokenizer and index the data.

Define a new `searchHandler` with this (above defined) field as default search field and call it when you have queries coming with white spaces.

Comment: @YoungHobbit unfortunately the problem is not with the white spaces but with the quotes - a white-spaced query without quotes gives multiple hits, as it is supposed to, but the quoted query gives zero when it should give a single hit.

Comment: @knirirr that is right, because the meaning of double quotes is that the string will be searched in the index as it as. So we can remove the quotes from the input string and search it into the new searcher which I have suggested you.