# How to search for "Apache Lucene" in Solr words that include spaces?

Tags: mysql, magento, solr

I am working on an ecommerce project in which we are using Solr search engine. If I search for "Apache Lucene" with SPACE, it gives the search results for "Apache Lucene" or "Apache" or "Lucene" but i only want "Apache Lucene" .So, here I am looking for EXACT MATCH of MULTIPLE WORDS that includes WHite SPACES.Can somebody please suggest me any solution?

Comment: Can you please use `"` to make your question clearer. I am having trouble what you mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [solr query with white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790180/solr-query-with-white-space)

Comment: @tkja hey hie. I already went through that link but didn't help me out. Do you know something else?

Comment: Do you want to include documents that have "Apache Solr Lucene" or "Lucene from Apache" etc.?

Comment: @MatsLindh I just want to include documents that has both "Apache Lucene". The problem I am facing is when i search for "Apache Lucene", solr is not taking both the words together because of whitespace and so I get the following results- documents having "Apache", "Lucene" or "Apache Lucene" .So I need solve the problem of white space so that i can retrieve documents that have both "Apache Lucene"

Comment: Yes, my question was whether they have to be placed after each other in the correct sequence, or if they can be anywhere within the text. The first would be a phrase query (which should work with `field:"apache lucene"`), the latter is either `mm=100%` (or a different `mm` setting if you want a different match profile) or `q.op=AND` (both with (e)dismax).

Comment: @Enigmativity Magento Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of the Magento e-Commerce platform. As per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it states `software tools commonly used by programmers`. This is question relation to Solr under [solr]. It's cool

Comment: @darthsidious - You missed half of the quote - it states `"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"`. Simply being a tool used by programmers is not enough - the question must be about software development too.

Answer (score 0):

As @MatsLindh pointed out. You can use the [Dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) or the [eDisMax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) querying capability instead of the [Standard Query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) for phrased queries. You have to set `mm=100%` for DisMax or `q.op=AND` .